# How do I use CSS transitions when adding elements in Elm?

Tags: css, css-transitions, elm

Simple scenario is I have a button that fetches some data from an API and adds the data to a list.

I would like to apply a CSS transition of the opacity property for the newly added item so it fades in as its added to the list.

Usually this is done by having a default CSS class with `opacity: 0;` and a `transition` rule. Then after the element is added you apply another CSS class to it with `opacity: 1;` and you get a fade in effect.

How do you do this with Elm?

This is how list items are added to the view right now,

`ul [ class "list" ] (List.map (\item -> li [] [ text item ]) model.items)`

Comment: Same way. Append element, add class.

Comment: @Justinas There's a timing issue here that needs to be solved. I don't append elements, Elm renders a list based on a List in the Model.

Comment: You can add a default class to the li as well `ul [ class "unsorted-list" ] (List.map (\item ->li [class "list-item hidden"] [ text item ]) model.items)` and remove the class `hidden` directly after this line,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Amir said is really the only thing you need to add. Elm will work with that just fine.

If you run into any issues, you might try to use [Html.Keyed package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Keyed), which should get rid of bugs with ordering / adding / deleting - you just use `Html.Keyed.ul`, which expects children to be not `Html msg` but `(String, Html msg)`. So typically you'd have some kind of ID for the row element. **(Edit: for example adding to front of the list would seem as adding to back with this code. See [here](https://ellie-app.com/M7nZJ5mCsja1/3) for updated example.)**

So, to expand on Amir's answer with some Elm code ([Ellie link](https://ellie-app.com/M7nZJ5mCsja1/1)):

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html as H exposing (Html)
import Html.Events as HE


type alias Model =
    { rows : List String }


type Msg
    = AddText


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    H.beginnerProgram
        { model = model
        , update = update
        , view = view
        }


model : Model
model =
    { rows = [] }


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        AddText ->
            { model | rows = model.rows ++ [ "Another row" ] }


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    H.div []
        [ H.button [ HE.onClick AddText ] [ H.text "add new row" ]
        , H.ul [] (List.map viewRow model.rows)
        ]


viewRow : String -> Html Msg
viewRow row =
    H.li [] [ H.text row ]
```

And the accompanying HTML (see the CSS):

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html {
      background: #F7F7F7;
      color: red;
    }
    li {
      animation: fadein 2s;
    }

    @keyframes fadein {
        from { opacity: 0; }
        to   { opacity: 1; }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an animation to achieve this like below

```js
var para = document.createElement("P");                       // Create a <p> element
var t = document.createTextNode("Element added with Javascript");       // Create a text node
para.appendChild(t);                                          // Append the text to <p>
para.className = 'animation-enter'                            // Add animation enter
document.body.appendChild(para);                              // Append <p> to <body>
```

```css
.animation-enter{
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<p class="animation-enter">On page Load </p>
```